# Can Pluralsight milestones be displayed in a different way (without imgur)?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, developer-story, pluralsight-iq

Pluralsight Skill IQ scores are apparently shown as images from imgur. In my brilliant country(and perhaps in some other countries / or ISPs) some sites such as https://imgur.com/ (it may be hard to comprehend but http://pastebin.com/ even) are banned by a court of law.

Which makes it hard for me to show off my Pluralsight Skill IQ score(s)(I'm an entry-level job seeker so this would really be helpful).

Would it be somehow possible to alter this? Perhaps be drawn dynamically? Or in another way indicate the score at the very least as images' hyperlink just as in adding images to posts?

[image: This description can be read for example]

Comment: Well then, nobody can browse imgurs /r/gonewild portfolio in turkey. Didn't know they banned those websites.This seems like a good candidate for formatting with either css or rendering on canvas using javascript.

Comment: @Tschallacka Well, you can penetrate this with vpn and such but in this case, one is supposed to _look for what isn't there_.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've just made it so that we're now including an `alt` element that can be used to see the score.

The `alt` for the card is `Title: <assessmentTitle> - Score: <score>/300`. The `alt` for the header element is `Score: <score>/300`.

This is going to be live on our next build.

Comment: but.... Comic Sans?

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems to be live now!

Answer (score 23):

We could use a simple css markup to achieve the same. Stack overflow just has to retrieve the scores somehow.

I don't know the fonts that were used, so I guessed comic sans and tahoma :P

```css
.pluralsight {
   float: left;
   padding-bottom:3px;
   border-bottom: 1px dotted #222;
}
.pluralsight .scores {
   display: inline-block;
   float: left;
   color: #222;
   font-family: Tahoma;
}
.pluralsight .IQ {
   display: inline-block;
   float: left;
   background: #26c1fb;
   padding:10px;
   font-size:30px;
   margin-right: 10px;
   color: white;
   font-family: "Comic Sans MS","Arial";
   border-radius: 50% 50% 0px 50%;
}
.pluralsight .scores .expert {
  font-size:35px;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-weight:800;
  color: #26c1fb;
}
.pluralsight .scores .expert .number {
    color: #222;
    font-weight:600;
}
.pluralsight .scores .verified {
    font-weight:600;
    letter-spacing:0.6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pluralsight">
  <div class="IQ">
    IQ
  </div>
  <div class="scores">
    <div class="expert">
      EXPERT 
      <span class="number">
        204
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="verified">
      VERIFIED 
      <span class="number">
        2.2018
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Combined with an onload handler, you could use it as a fallback mechanism, as suggested by [Allison](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2263507/alisson)

```css
.pluralsight-score-image {
   display:none;
}
.pluralsight {
   float: left;
   padding-bottom:3px;
   border-bottom: 1px dotted #222;
}
.pluralsight .scores {
   display: inline-block;
   float: left;
   color: #222;
   font-family: Tahoma;
}
.pluralsight .IQ {
   display: inline-block;
   float: left;
   background: #26c1fb;
   padding:10px;
   font-size:30px;
   margin-right: 10px;
   color: white;
   font-family: "Comic Sans MS","Arial";
   border-radius: 50% 50% 0px 50%;
}
.pluralsight .scores .expert {
  font-size:35px;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-weight:800;
  color: #26c1fb;
}
.pluralsight .scores .expert .number {
    color: #222;
    font-weight:600;
}
.pluralsight .scores .verified {
    font-weight:600;
    letter-spacing:0.6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Broken image load:<BR/><BR/>
<div class="plural-wrap">
  <img src="pluralsight-imageurl" onload="$(this).show();$(this).parent().find('.pluralsight').hide();" class="pluralsight-score-image">
  <div class="pluralsight">
    <div class="IQ">
      IQ
    </div>
    <div class="scores">
      <div class="expert">
        EXPERT 
        <span class="number">
          204
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="verified">
        VERIFIED 
        <span class="number">
          2.2018
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div style="clear:both"></div>
<BR/>
Working image load.<BR/><BR/>

<div class="plural-wrap">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWmk6.png" onload="$(this).show();$(this).parent().find('.pluralsight').hide();" class="pluralsight-score-image">
  <div class="pluralsight">
    <div class="IQ">
      IQ
    </div>
    <div class="scores">
      <div class="expert">
        EXPERT 
        <span class="number">
          204
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="verified">
        VERIFIED 
        <span class="number">
          2.2018
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This could be used as a fallback for those countries which banned imgur, for example.

Comment: Added a fallback example :-)

Comment: I love that you used Comic Sans.

Comment: Either they would have to request the scores every time someone opens up the developer story, or they'd require an async job to get updated scores for all users who have linked their scores in the developer story. Both of these methods seem inefficient to me. Though I though they might be requesting an image from Pluralsigh, but if that image is coming from imgur, I guess they are using a variant of these methods right now.

Comment: @NisargShah if the reponse has header like  <ID>_<date>_<score> it would contain all you need in the response, even if the imgur link data in the payload is non-renderable.

Comment: "So I guess Comic Sans and Tahoma" - close enough :)